# Calling a git repo in packages.yml in working dbt project

Tags: dbt

I have a git repo of dbt project. I want to use the macros from this project in a new dbt project. So, I call on that repo in packages.yml file of working dbt project. The instructions are here - https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management

However, I see a run time error which I am unable to debug. Any suggestions are appreciated

[Error Message Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKFnc.png)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing the dbt_project.yml file in the git repo you are trying to include as a package. Or, the dbt_project.yml may not be in the expected place. Per the [dbt documentation about packages](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management)

> In general, dbt expects dbt_project.yml to be located as a top-level file in a package. If the project is instead nested in a subdirectory—perhaps within a much larger monorepo—you can optionally specify the folder path as subdirectory. dbt will attempt a sparse checkout of just the files located within that subdirectory. Note that you must be using a recent version of git (>=2.25.0).